# PHP preg_split if not inside curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, programming-languages, preg-split

I'm makin' a scripting language interpreter using PHP. I have this code in that scripting language:

```
write {Hello, World!} in either the color {blue} or {red} or {#00AA00} and in either the font {Arial Black} or {Monaco} where both the color and the font are determined randomly
```

(Yes, it's hard to believe but that's the syntax)

Which regex must I use to split this (split by spaces) but only if not inside the curly brackets. So I want to turn the above code into this array:

1. write
2. **Hello, World!**
3. in
4. either
5. the
6. color
7. **blue**
8. or
9. **red**
10. or
11. **#00AA00**
12. and
13. in
14. either
15. the
16. font
17. **Arial Black**
18. or
19. **Monaco**
20. where
21. both
22. the
23. color
24. and
25. font
26. are
27. determined
28. randomly

(The strings inside the curly brackets are show above in **bold**)
The strings inside the curly brackets must be one element each. So {Hello, World!} cannot be:
 1. Hello,
 2. World!

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about using something like this :

```
$str = 'write {Hello, World!} in either the color {blue} or {red} or {#00AA00} and in either the font {Arial Black} or {Monaco} where both the color and the font are determined randomly';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('#\{.*?\}|[^ ]+#', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Which will get you :

```
array
  0 => string 'write' (length=5)
  1 => string '{Hello, World!}' (length=15)
  2 => string 'in' (length=2)
  3 => string 'either' (length=6)
  4 => string 'the' (length=3)
  5 => string 'color' (length=5)
  6 => string '{blue}' (length=6)
  7 => string 'or' (length=2)
  8 => string '{red}' (length=5)
  9 => string 'or' (length=2)
  10 => string '{#00AA00}' (length=9)
  11 => string 'and' (length=3)
  12 => string 'in' (length=2)
  13 => string 'either' (length=6)
  14 => string 'the' (length=3)
  15 => string 'font' (length=4)
  16 => string '{Arial Black}' (length=13)
  17 => string 'or' (length=2)
  18 => string '{Monaco}' (length=8)
  19 => string 'where' (length=5)
  20 => string 'both' (length=4)
  21 => string 'the' (length=3)
  22 => string 'color' (length=5)
  23 => string 'and' (length=3)
  24 => string 'the' (length=3)
  25 => string 'font' (length=4)
  26 => string 'are' (length=3)
  27 => string 'determined' (length=10)
  28 => string 'randomly' (length=8)
```

The, you just have to iterate over those results ; the ones starting by { and ending by } will be your "important" words, and the others will be the rest.

Edit after the comment : one way to identify the important words would be something like this :

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $word) {
    $m = array();
    if (preg_match('#^\{(.*)\}$#', $word, $m)) {
        echo '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($m[1]) . '</strong>';
    } else {
        echo htmlspecialchars($word);
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Or, like you said, working with strpos and strlen would work too ;-)

Comment: Thanks a thousand it worked! Now I just remove the { and } if they are at position 0 and strlen(arr[a]) - 1

Answer (score 0):

Does the order matter? If not you could extract all {}'s, remove them, then operate on the leftover string.

Comment: Yes it does, since {Hello, World!} could also be {This is an English word which is used very often: in} and I can't do a <code>continue;</code> when it sees that there's the word 'in'.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace them using [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). With the callback you can keep track of the order and replace them with something like %var1%, %var2%, etc.

I don't think that there is a way to explode by spaces, but not in the curly brackets without modifying the string beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done iterately without regexp. You iterate over the entire string. You put every character in a temporary variable, unless you find a space. When you find a space, you put the content of the temporary variable in the array, empty it, and then continue.

If you find a bracket, you set a boolean, and then put everything in the temp var, until you find a closing bracket. And so on.

```
<?php
$string = "write {Hello, World!} in either the color {blue} or {red} or {#00AA00} and in either the font {Arial Black} or {Monaco} where both the color and the font are determined randomly";
$bracket = false;
$words = array();
$temp = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){    
    $char = $string[$i]
    if($bracket){
        $temp .= $char;
        if($char == "}"){
            $bracket = false;
            $words[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($char == " "){
            if($temp != ""){
                $words[] = $temp;
                $temp = "";
            }
        }
        elseif($char == "{"}{
            $temp .= $char;
            $bracket = true;
        }
        else{
            $temp .= $char;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Code is untested.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split on all spaces that are not contained within curly braces.

Match the curly expressions or a sequence of non-whitespace characters then disregard these matches with `\K` then use the following space as the delimiter.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3RYto))

```
$text = 'write {Hello, World!} in either the color {blue} or {red} or {#00AA00} and in either the font {Arial Black} or {Monaco} where both the color and the font are determined randomly';

var_export(preg_split('~({[^}]*}|\S+)\K ~', $text));
```

p.s. You can replace curly braces with strong tags like this: https://3v4l.org/fXrgE

p.p.s. You could build your exact ordered list with `preg_replace_callback()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y4Q44)) <-- transfer to phptester.net to see it rendered

```
$text = 'write {Hello, World!} in either the color {blue} or {red} or {#00AA00} and in either the font {Arial Black} or {Monaco} where both the color and the font are determined randomly';

echo "<ol>" , preg_replace_callback('~{([^}]*)}|(\S+)~', function($m) {
        if (!isset($m[2])) {
            return "<li><strong>{$m[1]}</strong></li>\n";
        }
        return "<li>{$m[2]}</li>\n";
    },
    $text) , "<ol>";
```