# PHP preg_split curly brackets

Tags: php, regex, split, preg-split

Who can help me out?
I have a string like this:

```
$string = '<p>{titleInformation}<p>';
```

I want to split this string so that I get the following array:

```
array ( 
  0 => '<p>',
  1 => '{titleInformation}', 
  2 => '<p>',
)
```

I'm new to regular expressions and I tried multiple patterns with the preg_match_all() function but I cant get the correct one. Also looked at this question [PHP preg_split if not inside curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351980/php-preg-split-if-not-inside-curly-brackets?newreg=11d8dd87009b4826b5430ab76a09b084), but I don't have spaces in my string.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be addressed with regular expressions? It's a trivial task with e.g. `DOMDocument`.

Comment: How come `<p>` instead of `</p>` as a closing tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match()` with capture groups. You need to escape the curly braces because they have special meaning in regular expressions.

```
preg_match('/(.*?)(\\{[^}]*\\})(.*)/', $string, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "<p>{titleInformation}<p>"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "<p>"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "{titleInformation}"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "<p>"
}
```

`$match[0]` contains the match for the entire regexp, elements 1-3 contain the parts that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best function to call for your task is: `preg_split()`.  It has a `flag` called `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` which allows you to retain your chosen delimiter in the output array.  It is a very simple technique to follow and using `negated character classes` (`[^}]*`) is a great way to speed up your code.  Further benefits of using `preg_split()` versus `preg_match()` include:

- improved efficiency due to less capture groups
- shorter pattern which is easier to read
- no useless "fullstring" match in the output array

Code: ([PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/ffOLV)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7oQIz/1))

```
$string = '<p>{titleInformation}<p>';
var_export(
    preg_split('/({[^}]*})/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<p>',
  1 => '{titleInformation}',
  2 => '<p>',
)
```

If this answer doesn't work for all of your use cases, please edit your question to include the sample input strings and ping me -- I will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

With `preg_split` it can be done this way

```
preg_split('/[{}]+/', $myString);
```